# Error messages multilevel imputation with MICE

Tags: r, warnings, r-mice

I try to impute a dataset in R taking into account its multilevel structure.

```
pred2 <- make.predictorMatrix(Scales)

#Cluster

#Variables not imputed
pred2 [c("stud_id", "sg_idn", 
         "trs1jgs", "s12tt", "trs1juel", "s1alt",
         "s1ukab", "s1uukb", "s1umob", "s1utpb", 
         "ABrating", "ABrandom"),] <-0

#Variables not predicting
pred2 [,c("stud_id","s1ukab","s1uukb", "s1umob", "s1utpb", 
         "ABrating", "ABrandom")] <-0

pred2 [,"sg_idn"] <- -2

pred2
write.csv2(pred2, file = "Predictormatrix_02.csv")

### Make method
meth2 <- make.method(Scales)
meth2 [] <- "2l.pmm"
meth2 [c("stud_id", "sg_idn", 
         "trs1jgs", "s12tt", "trs1juel", "s1alt",
         "s1ukab", "s1uukb", "s1umob", "s1utpb", 
         "ABrating", "ABrandom")] <- ""

meth2

imp1 <- mice(Scales, m=5, method=meth2, predictorMatrix=pred2, maxit=5, seed=1234)
```

However, I encounter several problems:
I receive four different warnings:

1. In stats::runif(N, 0, fg1/noise) : NAs produziert
2. In NextMethod() :
   number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
3. In imputes[cc] <- do.call(f, args = args) :
   number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
4. Additionally, for 5 out of my 45 variables there is:
   boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')

What do the warnings mean? Is there a possibility to resolve the problems?